# Is there any way to run the following code to get the historical data of the stock

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, webdriver

I want to automatically get data from the NSE site link of which I have mentioned in my code. The issue I am facing is that the Get Data button on the website is not working with the code and the browser gets stuck without displaying any data thereafter. Moreover, I have written a panda code to get the data on the webpage after filling in all the information but that is also not working.

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
import time 
import pandas as pd 
a=input("Symbol\n") 
web=webdriver.Chrome()  
web.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm') 
time.sleep(5) 
Data=web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dataType"]/option[1]')
Data.click() 
Symbol=web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="symbol"]') 
Symbol.send_keys(a) 
Month=web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dateRange"]/option[8]') 
Month.click() 
time.sleep(2) 
Go=web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="get"]') 
Go.click()   
df=pd.read_html('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm')   
print(df[0])
```

Comment: Hi rahul. There is a library called yfinance from where you can download equities OHLCV and also stock financials in realtime (almost 5 seconds delayed). If you want weekly options data then you can use yahoo_fin library. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me by using java script executor

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, warnings


a=input("Symbol: ")

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm')
 
time.sleep(5)
 
Data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dataType"]/option[1]')
Data.click() 

Symbol = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="symbol"]') 
Symbol.send_keys(a)
 
Month = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dateRange"]/option[8]') 
Month.click() 

time.sleep(2) 

driver.execute_script("javascript:document.getElementById('submitMe').click()")
#driver.execute_script("javascript:submitData();") ## this one also works
```